# How to add a package stereotype in tikz-uml?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I need to draw an "extended" uml diagram for problem frames. For this purpose I installed tikz-uml (because I am also using tikz for other drawings).

My packages need a stereotype, but the tikz-uml docs don't say anything about that.
I would like to have a type attribute to define a stereotype.
The code below does not compile.

```
\tikzset{
  type/.style={%
    draw,
    font={\guillemotleft #1 \guillemotright \\}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{umlpackage}[type=contextDiagram,x=0,y=0]{package-name} 
\end{umlpackage} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So this is what I want to achieve:

[image: uml diagram with one contextDiadgram package]

Or is there another packege, which is more powerfull?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ugly, because it requires renewing the definition of a fairly complex environment that was not designed to do this (traditional UML would not have stereotypes for packages). But it gets the job done.

I assume release v1.0b (01 February 2013) of `tikz-uml`, available for download [here](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en).

The added code is mostly borrowed from the equivalent code in the definition of the internal `\umlclass` command, which *does* support stereotypes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for guillemots (package doc uses babel to fake them)
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{umlpackage}[2][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/package/.cd,%
           x/.initial=0, y/.initial=0,%
           name/.initial=tikzumlEmpty, draw/.initial=\tikzumldrawcolor, type/.initial=\empty,% 
           fill/.initial=\tikzumlfillpackagecolor, text/.initial=\tikzumltextcolor,%
           .unknown/.code={%
             \let\keyname=\pgfkeyscurrentname%
             \errmessage{TIKZUML ERROR : in umlpackage, invalid option \keyname}%
                                }}%
  \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/package/.cd, #1}%
  \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/package/.cd,%
           x/.get=\xshift, y/.get=\yshift, name/.get=\tikzumlpackagename,%
           draw/.get=\tikzumlpackagedraw, fill/.get=\tikzumlpackagefill,%
           text/.get=\tikzumlpackagetext, type/.get=\umlpackagetype,}%
  %
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\umlpackagetype}{}}{%
    \def\tikzumlpackagetype{}%
  }{%
    \def\tikzumlpackagetype{\guillemotleft\umlpackagetype\guillemotright \\}%
  }%
  \ifnum\thetikzumlPackageLevel>0%
    \let\tikzumlPackage@nameold\tikzumlPackage@fitname%
    \def\tikzumlPackage@name{#2}%
    \begingroup%
      \def\_{@}\edef\x{\endgroup%
        \def\noexpand\tikzumlPackage@fitname{\tikzumlPackage@name}}\x%
    \let\tikzumlPackage@parentold\tikzumlPackage@parent%
    \edef\tikzumlPackage@parent{\tikzumlPackage@parentold @@\tikzumlPackage@nameold}%
  \else%
    \def\tikzumlPackage@parent{}%
    \def\tikzumlPackage@name{#2}%
    \begingroup%
      \def\_{@}\edef\x{\endgroup%
        \def\noexpand\tikzumlPackage@fitname{\tikzumlPackage@name}}\x%
  \fi%
  %
  \let\tikzumlPackage@nodeNameold\tikzumlPackage@nodeName%
  %  
  \begingroup%
    \def\_{_}\edef\x{\endgroup%
      \def\noexpand\tikzumlPackage@nodeName{\tikzumlPackage@name}}\x%
  %
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlpackagename}{tikzumlEmpty}}{}{%
    \def\tikzumlPackage@nodeName{\tikzumlpackagename}%
  }%
  %
  \StrSubstitute{\tikzumlPackage@nodeName}{.}{@POINT@}{\tikzumlPackage@nodeName}%
  %
  \expandafter\gdef\csname tikzumlPackageFit\tikzumlPackage@parent @@\tikzumlPackage@fitname\endcsname{}%
  %
  \setcounter{tikzumlPackageClassNum}{0}%
  \setcounter{tikzumlPackageSubPackageNum}{0}%
  \stepcounter{tikzumlPackageLevel}%
  %
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\xshift cm, yshift=\yshift cm]%
}{%
  \addtocounter{tikzumlPackageLevel}{-1}%
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{package\thetikzumlPackageLevel}%
  %
  % if contains no class, one define a fictive node to enable the fit option
  \ifnum\c@tikzumlPackageClassNum=0%
    \ifnum\c@tikzumlPackageSubPackageNum=0%
      \node[inner sep=1.5ex] (\tikzumlPackage@nodeName-root) at (0,0) {\phantom{\tikzumlPackage@nodeName}};%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlPackageFit\tikzumlPackage@parent @@\tikzumlPackage@fitname\endcsname{(\tikzumlPackage@nodeName-root)}%
      %
    \fi%
  \fi%
  %
  \ifnum\c@tikzumlPackageLevel>0%
    \def\tikzumlPackageFitTmp{\csname tikzumlPackageFit\tikzumlPackage@parent\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlPackageFit\tikzumlPackage@parent\endcsname{\tikzumlPackageFitTmp (\tikzumlPackage@nodeName) (\tikzumlPackage@nodeName-caption)}%
    \stepcounter{tikzumlPackageSubPackageNum}%
  \fi%
  %
  \node[draw=\tikzumlpackagedraw, fill=\tikzumlpackagefill, text=\tikzumlpackagetext, font=\tikzumlfont, inner sep=1.5ex, fit = \csname tikzumlPackageFit\tikzumlPackage@parent @@\tikzumlPackage@fitname\endcsname] (\tikzumlPackage@nodeName) {};%
  \node[draw=\tikzumlpackagedraw, fill=\tikzumlpackagefill, text=\tikzumlpackagetext, font=\tikzumlfont, minimum height=1.5em, outer ysep=-0.3, anchor=south west,align=center] (\tikzumlPackage@nodeName-caption) at (\tikzumlPackage@nodeName.north west) {\tikzumlpackagetype \textbf{\tikzumlPackage@name}};%
  \end{pgfonlayer}%
  \end{scope}%
}%
\makeatother
\tikzumlset{font={\small\sffamily}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{umlpackage}[x=0,y=0,type=contextDiagram]{package-name} 
\end{umlpackage} 
\begin{umlpackage}[x=5,y=0]{package-name-no-type} 
\end{umlpackage} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might consider using [`pgf-umlcd`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-umlcd) instead. It looks to support many of the same things that `tikz-uml` does, but `pgf-umlcd` is on CTAN (more officially accessible) and has developer activity in the last year (not great, I know, but the same cannot be said for `tikz-uml`). However, `pgf-umlcd` does not support package stereotypes either, so modifications would be required there too.

Answer (score 1):

I added this feature to tikz-uml. A new release will be available soon. I was quite away from tikz-uml until now but the package will live again.